# How to hide part of the image?

Tags: css

I need to do this:

if the image has an height higher of 100px then hide the rest of the image ( example: image with height of 80px -> show full image, image with height of 150px -> show only the first 100px ).

Is there a way to do that with CSS ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the `max-height` property to specify the maximum height of the image, and then use `overflow: hidden;` to hide anything else.

e.g.

HTML:

```
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="some-image.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-container {
  max-height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

JSFiddle Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/3jA9q/

**EDIT**

For internet explorer 6, you can use [CSS expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to emulate something similar:

```
.image-container {
  height:expression(this.scrollHeight<100?"auto":"100px");
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Do note however that this requires that the user have JavaScript enabled in their browser. My experience with CSS expressions however have been pretty poor, and they're best avoided.

Comment: @xRobot It does starting with IE7 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/max-height#Browser_compatibility

Comment: You're only alternative with internet explorer 6 and earlier would be to use `height` as @Jcubed said.

Comment: This hides the image from the bottom... How to do it from the top?

Answer (score 8):

You can do it using a combnation of `max-height` and `overflow`.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    max-height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Also note that `max-height` doesn't work in older browsers, but if you used normal `height` then images could never be shorter than 100px either.

Comment: but if I use height then images with height of 50px will be distorted.

Comment: I was talking about using height on the div, not the img. An image 50px tall in a 100px div will not be distorted, but will simply have a 50px gap after it.

Comment: @xRobot - They should be fine, since you're setting the size of the wrapper div, not the image itself. You will however have big gaps under the image, which is undesirable, but possibly undesirable with... older browsers.

Comment: @Jcubed - Given our answers and responses, I'm starting to think we may be the same person :P

Answer (score 4):

Put it in a div with a height of 100px and set `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 3):

You can use clip property

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);
}
```

Comment: For anyone seeing this now it's recommended to use the clip-path property as clip is depreciated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path